# How do you properly use "write" in Applescript?

Tags: arrays, macos, applescript

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly use "write" in applescript. I currently have code like this:

```
set randomArray to {"hello", "text", "file"}
set saveFile to (path to desktop as text) & "RandomFile.txt"

write randomArray to saveFile starting at eof as list
```

I know that this is not right, but I can't seem to figure out what the correct thing to put where "saveFile" is would be.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, it is totally right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example to write to a file can be found in the code-snippet *(CTRL-Click into a script to see them)* `Error Handlers`, `Write Error to Log`.

To save an array/list you can use something like this:

```
set randomArray to {"hello", "text", "file"}
set fullText to ""

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in randomArray
    set thisItem to item i of randomArray

    set fullText to fullText & thisItem
    if i is not number of items in randomArray then set fullText to fullText & return

end repeat

my scriptLog(fullText)

on scriptLog(thisText)
    set the logFilePath to ((path to desktop) as text) & "Script Log.txt"
    try
        open for access file the logFilePath with write permission
        write (thisText & return) to file the logFilePath starting at eof
        close access file the logFilePath
    on error
        try
            close access file the logFilePath
        end try
    end try
end scriptLog
```

Comment: This script will to in an "else if" statement. When I try to compile it, it expects to see an "else" where the on is in "on scriptLog".

Answer (score 1):

As zero mentioned you need to open the file before writing into it. After writing you have to close the access. BTW reading a whole file is possible with one call of the read handler.
Another point in your question is that you want to write a list. This is possible of course, but you'll need to read the content as list, too. Putting all together and taking the main points from zero's answer, we get this:

```
set randomArray to {"hello", "text", "file"}
set saveFile to (path to desktop as text) & "RandomFile.txt"

-- write the file
set theFilehandle to open for access file saveFile with write permission
write (randomArray) to theFilehandle starting at eof as list
close access theFilehandle

-- read the file
read file saveFile as list
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: You don't need to open for access before your read and write, only if you need to create the file.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks!  I remember that I read about it in the past. But I never tried that, I think that creating the file automatically if it does not exist is always a good way.