# "Write" in Applescript adds things to text

Tags: macos, text, applescript

I am relatively new to applescript, so I apologize if this is a silly question. When I `write (text & return) to file the randomFile starting at eof` it adds "listutxtplaceholderutxtº" to the beginning and "utxt!utxt" to the end, making it so that these things show up when I `read` the file. Why is it doing this? Is there a workaround?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is already text that says "placeholder" in the file.

Comment: Did you try to `read as list`? Please read Zero's answer and the answers given to your other question Zero mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when the content in your variable is a `list`.

Make sure it's not a list or handle it as a list ([you already know how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733898/how-do-you-properly-use-write-in-applescript/29734500#29734500)).

But when that `list` only has one item you can use `as text`, like that:

```
set myList to {"Hi"} -- this is a list with one item
write ((myList as text) & return) to file the randomFile starting at eof
```

From the `Apple Script Language Guide`:

> **List**
>   A list defines an ordered collection of values, known as items,
>   of any class. As depicted in a script, a list consists of a series of
>   expressions contained within braces and separated by commas, such as
>   the following:
>
> `{1, 7, "Beethoven", 4.5}`
>
> A list can contain other lists. An empty list (containing no items) is
>   represented by a pair of empty braces: `{}`.
>
> AppleScript provides the `list class` for working with lists.